# What is better way to put data in mongo ? create Single collection with loads of data in array or create multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to create collection where search will be on multiple fields. Should I seperate collections for each seperate field or I have to put fields inside array or object, from where I have to use search query. Which is better? To search id from one collection based on element search and go to another collection to find rest data OR use search within an array or object in a collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without example it is hard to tell, but generally, if you have more than few GBs in one collection, then it will be better to split it.